# PHP: Is it possible to call a public class function inside of an exception throw?

Tags: php, class, exception

I am trying to get this litte demo to run, but I keep getting a plain string

```
"getConfiguration:Name (self::getName())is not supported"
```

(when using self::getName())

or an error-messege:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined property: Demo::$getName
```

(when using $this->getName())

This is my Code:

```
    class Demo {
        protected $name = "demo";

        public function __construct() {
          try {
                if(true) {
                    throw new Exception("Name (self::getName())" .
                                        "is not supported");
                }
          } catch(Exception $e){
            echo $e->getMessage(); exit;
          }
        }

       public function getName() {
           return $this->demo;
       }
   }
```

Now is this simply not possible or am I doing something wrong here?!

EDIT:

Before this I got this working with `$this->name`, but I would rather use a function if it is possible and not somehow a very bad idea.

Comment: you can't do this in exception but you can achieve this by register_shut_down function for any errors

Comment: You are getting a plain string because you capture the exception with try/catch and then downgrade it to string with `echo`. What do you want to accomplish by triggering an exception and immediately cancelling it?

Comment: He is right. Either just throw the exception and let it be handled by whatever error handler there is or just echo and exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling a function statically that is not static. Referencing to $this might also be problematic inside a construcotr, especially if it failed.

You should also change your Exception to not contain the call inside a string.

```
throw new Exception("Name (".self::getName().") is not supported");
```

Change your method to static access. You will also have to make your variable $demo static:

```
   protected static $name;

   public static function getName() {
       return self::$name;
   }
```

---

Throwing an exception just to get an echo doesnt make that much sense. You should either just echo your error and exit or throw an exception:

```
    public function __construct() {
        throw new Exception("Name (".self::getName().") is not supported");
    }
```

OR

```
    public function __construct() {
        echo "Name (".self::getName().") is not supported";
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: it will throw an error like this: 'using $this when not in object context'

Comment: changed it to static too.

Comment: Plz also see comments of Alvaro G. Vicario on question. Your logic doesnt make that much sense.

Comment: thank you very much, now I see the flaw in my idea ;)